# remove video support from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video

I would like to prevent Chrome from playing any video (flash, html5), how can I do this? I did try to delete the `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/43.0.2357.xxx/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Libraries/ffmpegsumo.so` library, but then page containing a video will not display at all. I would like to be able to read such a page, without the video playing.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? This sounds very contrived.

Comment: Indeed. Well... I need to stop watching videos to finish a big piece of work... I guess I'm not the only one who would benefit from this...